# Execute function stored in a variable

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to execute a function whose definition is stored in a variable in VBScript?
For example:

```
Set fun = "Sub fun" & 
          " MsgBox 1" &
          "End Sub"
```

the variable `fun` has the function definition so is it now possible to somehow execute this function using eval or something else?

Comment: If you look up `eval` in help it will tell you related functions at the bottom. Try it.

Comment: I think it is Execute statement.

Comment: Use `Call ExecuteGlobal("sub fun()" & vbCrLf & "msgbox 1" & vbCrLf & "end sub")`. That will dynamically create the procedure `fun()` but you'll still need to call it afterwards.

Comment: Note that doing this is not good practice and usually a sign of bad design choices.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with the use of [`ExecuteGlobal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1(v=vs.84).aspx).

```vb
Dim cmd : cmd = "Sub fun()" & vbCrLf & "MsgBox 1" & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
'Call ExecuteGlobal() to add the fun() procedure definition into the global scope.
Call ExecuteGlobal(cmd)
'Call the procedure now it's defined.
Call fun()
```

> **Note:** Depending on the context used, it would be wise to sanitise any input that is use to build the `ExecuteGlobal()` statement as it could be possible to inject unwanted code.