# How to specify a subroutine to call in the query string and execute it

Tags: asp-classic

The query string contains the form and func variables and other data. Based on this querystring a sub customer_display has to be called.

```
form=customer&func=display&otherdata=12...

ASP file

<%

'how to make the following line to call customer_display
Call  form & "_" & func


Sub customer_display
  ...
End Sub

%>
```

Comment: Use [`ExecuteGlobal()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/342311f1(v=vs.84)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute function stored in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40930191)